# Moving data into a different schema between postgreSQL databases

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a the same table in two databases within one postgres server.

I would like to know if it is possible to copy a table under schemaA in DB1 to schemaB in DB2.
Or alternatively, copy the data from a table under schemaA in DB1 to the equivalent empty schemaB in DB2.

I have researched a found the pg_dump code to be effective, however I would need to rename the schema to the destination schema before executing...

```
    pg_dump -t schemaAt.table 'DB1' | psql 'DB2'
```

I am also wondering if 'pg_restore' command can be used to to restore the data only into a new schema?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Does the new schema exist in the old database? If not, you can simply dump/restore (which would create the "old" name in the "new" database), then rename the schema to the new name. Or simply use a foreign table from `db2.schemab.table` to point to `db1.schemaa.table` then you don't need to copy anything. Or merge both databases into one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, the only way to do it involves renaming the schema because the dump always contains the source schema name. But this can be done easily like this.

```
./pg_dump -a -t schemaA.table -U postgres -d DB1 |sed 's/schemaA/schemaB/g'|  psql DB2 -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

The above command will copy the table schemaA.table data from Db1 to pre-existing table schemaB.table in DB2.

Answer (score 0):

COPY command will be useful, for data only. There are options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid dealing with commands, best thing would be, export data from DB1 in CSV or Text file and use classy GUI wizard of pgAdmin tool to import data in Postgres.